# React-Native Expo ошибка в компоненте TextInput

Tags: react-native

подскажите пожалуйста, почему выводит ошибку `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean abi44_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.FabricViewStateManager.hasStateWrapper()' on a null object reference`

Код выглядит следующий образом:

```
<TextInput
placeholder="Мобильный телефон"
style={Styles.login__controlInput}
/>
```

Примечательно что ошибку отображается только на Android.

Answer (score 0):

Если запускаете через expo go,  то скачайте в apk предыдущую версию 2.23.2. Мне помогло.